# Como posso rodar uma função quando utilizador se regista django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Eu estou a desenvolver um servidor utilizando django e queria que quando um utilizador se registasse rodasse uma função que iria criar uma directory com o nome do utilizador. A pasta com o nome do utilizador novo sera guardada em Collections. O meu código é o seguinte:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)  

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a user with the given variables and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password=None, is_admin=True):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given variables and password.
    """
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        is_admin = is_admin,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
 )
username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, unique=False)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, unique=False)
user_collection = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='NotCreated', unique=False)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin
```

**Imagem com directories**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione isto dentro da função "create_user":

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.mkdir(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Collections/{}'.format(self.username)))
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu esprimentei o codigo que mandou mas nao esta a funcionar eu tentei substituir por um print() para ver se esta a ser rodado mas nao esta a funcinar. Tem alguma recomendação?

Comment: Estranho, aqui deu certinho.
Colocou o código dentro do método save? Ao criar o usuário, o código deveria criar a pasta um nível acima do nível de sua app dentro da pasta Collections. 
Testou criando um user ou um super_user?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gPOIGzn <- Codigo                                                         Foto da consola -> https://imgur.com/Nw3OY2d

Comment: Afinal nao consegui. Sim eu coloquei dentro do create_user e create_superuser mas eu acho que estas funçoes nem se quer estao a ser rodadas pois eu coloquei um print(self.username) e nenhuma delas esta a criar qualquer output.

Comment: Você referenciou a class no settings.py? Caso não, adicione o seguinte: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mainAPP.UserManager'

Comment: Ja consegui que funcionasse